# How to prove that $e^x +1- \sin(x) > 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, alternative-proof

So I have found a solution but I don't think it's the best one.
So by saying that $$ |\sin x|\le 1 (\forall x \in R) \Rightarrow -1 \le \sin x \le 1 \Rightarrow 0 \le 1- \sin x$$ and if we add $$ +e^x $$ on both sides we get $$ e^x \le e^x +1 - \sin x $$ but because $$ e^x > 0 , \forall x \in R $$ we finally get:
$$ 0 < e^x \leq e^x + 1 -\sin x   \Rightarrow e^x+1-\sin x > 0$$

Is there a better way to prove this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: This seems extremely straight-forward to me

Comment: $e^x\ge0\ge\sin(x)-1$? I mean I don't see it getting much simpler than that.

Comment: Yeah, that can work as well, thanks! =)

Comment: You solution is *mas fino*, bro!  ***+1, endorsed!***

Comment: You can write it in the form $e^x+1>\sin x$ and see that it follows from the fact that $1 \geq \sin x$ and you have added a positive quantity $(e^x)$ on the left hand side. Which is more or less the same you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the derivative, thats the other way i can suggest. Of the function $F(x)=e^x +1- \sin(x) $

Comment: The derivative is $e^x-\cos x$, which, for $x\lt0$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative, so I'm not sure it's going to be of much help.